# Why can't I access mysql in php with password?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "Voyga");
```

it works well without password

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "Voyga", "password");
```

but it says `Access denied for user 'Voyga'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`i if I use password.

The password must be right because I can successfully use this password to access mysql in the command line. Why can't I use password if I try to connect mysql in php?

Comment: could be an issue with the privillages

Comment: try to connect it with root and see if its connecting. If yes, there could be some issues with your privileges/configurations !

Comment: can you run this after command-line connect success:  `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`

Answer (score 0):

Check your **username** and **password**

Path -  (xampp)`xampp\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php` or (wamp)`Wamp\apps\phpmyadmin[phpmyadmin version]\config.inc.php`

You can see something like

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';//username
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';//password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Comment: I just found that maybe the php is using the mysql installed with MAMP, and in the command line I'm using the stand-alone mysql I installed earlier. And I think that's why I can't access in php, I created a new user in MAMP mysql with phpmyadmin and then it works. How can I access the mysql installed with MAMP in command line?

Answer (score -1):

**This is example connect to mysql localhos**t

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');

define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');

define('DB_PASSWORD', ''); // set null if you don't use password to connect localhost

define('DB_DATABASE', ''); //your database name

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Might be an issue of privileges.
You can try using this instead.

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
```